# Joda time timezone parsing with region/city

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, date-parsing

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
                DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Copenhagen")
        );

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm dd MM YY Z");
        System.out.println(
                formatter.parseDateTime("19:30 29 8 11 Europe/Copenhagen")
        );
    }
}
```

I would expect this to to parse the date in Copenhagen timezone, and yet it fails with:

```
Europe/Copenhagen
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "19:30 29 8 11 Europe/Copenhagen" is malformed at "Europe/Copenhagen"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:683)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Why?

Comment: Because the docs say:
Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [JodaTime DateTimeFormat javadocs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for `DateTimeFormat`  you should use `ZZZ` not `Z`.

Its easy to miss since the table in that doc only shows Z. Down the page a bit is this, "Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id."

Comment: Trying ZZZ still throws the same exception for me: """Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "19:30 29 8 11 Europe/Copenhagen" is malformed at " Europe/Copenhagen""""

Comment: Hrmm. I see in the doc I linked that "Zone names: Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.", so maybe Joda can only output the zone but not parse it?

Comment: Looks like you have to do some preprocessing of the string on your own. http://joda-interest.219941.n2.nabble.com/Re-Parsing-short-timezones-td5786347.html . Its possible, but not supported as of a year ago.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing of time zone IDs like Europe/Copenhagen was only added in Joda-Time v2.0

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm using, which seems to be working so far is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatterC = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm dd M YY").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Copenhagen"));
    System.out.println(
        formatterC.parseDateTime("19:30 29 8 11")
    );
}
```

Comment: I think this is as close as you'll get. You can write a regex to parse out the time zone, `/ .*?\/.*? /`. Then feed that into `DateTimeZone.forId(strId)` to validate it. Finally make a call as you did above with the rest of the format, plus the additional `withZone`.